# EJB 3 performance with respect to scalability

Tags: java, performance, migration, ejb-3.0, scalability

We are planning to migrate our application from EJB 2 to EJB 3.
I understand the benefits of using EJB 3 with respect to Light weight component, DI and everything else, but what I am not sure is about the scalibilty in terms of users

Does EJB 3 have any benefits over EJB 2 with respect to scalability??

Comment: Which kind of scalability? Cross-machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ejb3 or Ejb2.1 are spec (API). 
The implementation is done by vendors (Jboss,Weblogic...) .
From the spec perspective as concern to "scalability" there is no difference between 2.1 to 3.
Moving from 2.1 to 3 under the same ejb-container vendor shouldn't impact performance or scalability ,because most likely that under the hoods there are implement the same